# Android studio 1.5.1: Could not find property 'vectorDrawables'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1, Gradle 2.8 and my project min sdk vserion:14, target sdk version: 23.

So, When I add vectorDrawables to configuration by documentation Google: [Added VectorDrawable support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html), I get following error:

```
Error:(13, 0) Could not find property 'vectorDrawables' on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=ApiVersionImpl{mApiLevel=14, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=ApiVersionImpl{mApiLevel=23, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=25, versionName=1.0.25, applicationId=com.smsoft.alibaba, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}.
```

this is my **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smsoft.alibaba"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 25
        versionName "1.0.25"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

Anybody know how to fix this problem ?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Gabriele Mariotti to signal for my confused between gradle and gradle plugin. I'm confused when reading the addition of Compact Vector Drawables instructions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you’re using **v2.0** or above of the **Gradle plugin** you have to use:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}
```

If you hare using **v1.5.0** or below of the **Gradle plugin** you need to add the following to your app’s `build.gradle`:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Stops the Gradle plugin’s automatic rasterization of vectors
    generatedDensities = []
  }
  // Flag to tell aapt to keep the attribute ids around
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

Don't confuse gradle with the gradle plugin. Check the `build.gradle` in the root folder (or inside the module) to get the version used by the gradle plugin (check the line `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'`)

Comment: Hi @Gabriele, I fixed my question and I forget add "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true" line to defaultConfig, after adding this line I got this error, look to above

Comment: Are you using the plugin 2.0 ?

Comment: @mr.boyfox Don't confuse gradle with the gradle plugin. 2.8 is the gradle version, not the plugin. Check the build.gradle in the root folder.

Comment: Oh, sorry you are right i use com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 build plugin

Comment: i dont get it. im using gradle 2+ still having the same error as OP

Comment: Your comments did the trick for me. Like @mr.boyfox was confused between gradle and gradle pugin.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Great if you could add this information to your answer as well.

Comment: @Mohit just added in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Specifically to upgrade from `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0`.

1. Edit /build.gradle and set:

   ```
   buildscript {
       ...
       dependencies {
           ...
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Edit /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and set:

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
   ```
3. Edit your module(s)' build.gradle and add:

   ```
   android {
       ...
       defaultConfig {
           ...
           vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: BTW, this may be off-topic, but today (2016/04/08) there is a mysterious comment about Support 23.3 that removes this feature from AppCompat pre-Lollipop devices:
https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/iTDmFiGrVne

Funny that there is no mention of this removal in the official release notes (that the above posting gives a link to):
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue with Gradle plugin on v3.4.2. It prevented project sync's from completing.

The issue was resolved by removing `vectorDrawables` and adding `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to the `defaultConfig`.

**OLD**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.diceroller"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }vectorDrawables
}
```

**NEW**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.diceroller"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u are having `useSupportLibary` in latest version 
Use

```java
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibary(true)
In your defaultconfig
```