# VectorDrawables and Instant Run with android gradle plugin

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-studio-2.0

I have been using the latest android support library, Gradle plugin, android Studio as they release. As with last few releases of android support library, the feature to support vectorDrawables natively was introduced and revoked with another support-lib update.

I heavily converted my project to use vectorDrawables but now i have to revert back to gradle plugin 1.5.0 that generated PNGs at build time.

Now cannot use the latest androidStudio 2.0 feature InstantRun because it requires Gradle 2.0.0 and higher.

Is it the curse of using latest features as they release?

What's the configuration to use both vectorDrawables and InstantRun at once?

Comment: so use  Gradle 2.0.0

Comment: VectorDrawables can be used with Gradle Plugin 1.5, [info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693288/android-studio-1-5-1-could-not-find-property-vectordrawables?rq=1). InstantRun requires AndroidStudio 2.0 & Gradle 2.0

Comment: @pskink so i cannot use vectorDrawable??

Comment: @Amy so i cannot use both features at once

Comment: so you want to use vectorDrawables or you want to use `generated PNGs at build time` ?

Comment: i want to use "both vectorDrawables and InstantRun" at once.

Comment: no more supports vectorDrawables natively with the latest support Lib.

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108880/discussion-between-arnav-m-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer here-- [AppCompat 23.3 Support Vectors no longer work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484748).

Just need to remove the following--

> vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true