# Why is my android vectordrawable crashing with a cannot inflate?

Tags: java, android

Here is my error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thing/com.thing.ReceiptActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class

VECTOR FILE (in my res/layout):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:viewportWidth="694"
        android:viewportHeight="978"
        android:layout_width="694dp"
        android:layout_height="978dp">
        <group
            android:translateX="2">
            <path
                android:pathData="M0 100L0 0l690 0 0 100c-11.0457 0 -20 8.95431 -20 20 0 11.04569 8.9543 20 20 20l0 613c-11.0457 0 -20 8.9543 -20 20 0 11.0457 8.9543 20 20 20l0 171.00272C690 969.52406 685.52581 974 679.99669 974L10.003313 974C4.4786356 974 0 969.5226 0 964.00272L0 793c11.045695 0 20 -8.9543 20 -20 0 -11.0457 -8.954305 -20 -20 -20L0 140c11.045695 0 20 -8.95431 20 -20 0 -11.04569 -8.954305 -20 -20 -20z"
                android:fillColor="#000000" />
            <path
                android:pathData="M0 100L0 0l690 0 0 100c-11.0457 0 -20 8.95431 -20 20 0 11.04569 8.9543 20 20 20l0 613c-11.0457 0 -20 8.9543 -20 20 0 11.0457 8.9543 20 20 20l0 171.00272C690 969.52406 685.52581 974 679.99669 974L10.003313 974C4.4786356 974 0 969.5226 0 964.00272L0 793c11.045695 0 20 -8.9543 20 -20 0 -11.0457 -8.954305 -20 -20 -20L0 140c11.045695 0 20 -8.95431 20 -20 0 -11.04569 -8.954305 -20 -20 -20z"
                android:fillColor="#ffffff" />
            <path
                android:pathData="M0 100L0 0l690 0 0 100c-11.0457 0 -20 8.95431 -20 20 0 11.04569 8.9543 20 20 20l0 613c-11.0457 0 -20 8.9543 -20 20 0 11.0457 8.9543 20 20 20l0 171.00272C690 969.52406 685.52581 974 679.99669 974L10.003313 974C4.4786356 974 0 969.5226 0 964.00272L0 793c11.045695 0 20 -8.9543 20 -20 0 -11.0457 -8.954305 -20 -20 -20L0 140c11.045695 0 20 -8.95431 20 -20 0 -11.04569 -8.954305 -20 -20 -20z"
                android:fillColor="#000000" />
            <path
                android:pathData="M0 100L0 0l690 0 0 100c-11.0457 0 -20 8.95431 -20 20 0 11.04569 8.9543 20 20 20l0 613c-11.0457 0 -20 8.9543 -20 20 0 11.0457 8.9543 20 20 20l0 171.00272C690 969.52406 685.52581 974 679.99669 974L10.003313 974C4.4786356 974 0 969.5226 0 964.00272L0 793c11.045695 0 20 -8.9543 20 -20 0 -11.0457 -8.954305 -20 -20 -20L0 140c11.045695 0 20 -8.95431 20 -20 0 -11.04569 -8.954305 -20 -20 -20z"
                android:fillColor="#ffffff" />
            <path
                android:pathData="M28.5 773l636 0"
                android:strokeWidth="4"
                android:strokeLineCap="square"
                android:strokeColor="#eceff4" />
            <group
                android:translateX="75"
                android:translateY="814">
                <path
                    android:pathData="M0 0l7.9852128 0 0 120L0 120Z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M24.953789 0l11.977817 0 0 120 -11.977817 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M45.91497 0l7.985213 0 0 120 -7.985213 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M88.835487 0l7.985213 0 0 120 -7.985213 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M117.78188 0l11.97782 0 0 120 -11.97782 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M15.970425 0l3.992606 0 0 120 -3.992606 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M62.883549 0l3.992606 0 0 120 -3.992606 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M78.853973 0l3.992607 0 0 120 -3.992607 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M105.80407 0l3.99261 0 0 120 -3.99261 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M136.74677 0l3.9926 0 0 120 -3.9926 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M146.72829 0l5.98891 0 0 120 -5.98891 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M157.70795 0l5.98891 0 0 120 -5.98891 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M176.67282 0l7.98521 0 0 120 -7.98521 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M196.63586 0l3.99261 0 0 120 -3.99261 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M205.61922 0l3.9926 0 0 120 -3.9926 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M221.58965 0l7.98521 0 0 120 -7.98521 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M240.55453 0l3.99261 0 0 120 -3.99261 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M299.44547 0l3.9926 0 0 120 -3.9926 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M309.427 0l3.99261 0 0 120 -3.99261 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M342.366 0l3.9926 0 0 120 -3.9926 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M355.34195 0l3.99261 0 0 120 -3.99261 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M363.32718 0l3.99261 0 0 120 -3.99261 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M376.30313 0l14.97227 0 0 120 -14.97227 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M398.26248 0l7.98521 0 0 120 -7.98521 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M411.23843 0l14.97228 0 0 120 -14.97228 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M430.20334 0l8.98336 0 0 120 -8.98336 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M443.17929 0l3.99261 0 0 120 -3.99261 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M455.1571 0l8.98337 0 0 120 -8.98337 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M468.13309 0l3.9926 0 0 120 -3.9926 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M487.09796 0l7.98521 0 0 120 -7.98521 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M508.05914 0l11.97782 0 0 120 -11.97782 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M524.0296 0l3.99261 0 0 120 -3.99261 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M533.01294 0L540 0l0 120 -6.98706 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M319.40851 0l3.9926 0 0 120 -3.9926 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M249.53789 0l11.97782 0 0 120 -11.97782 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M266.50647 0l11.97782 0 0 120 -11.97782 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
                <path
                    android:pathData="M283.47504 0l11.97781 0 0 120 -11.97781 0z"
                    android:fillColor="#252935" />
            </group>
        </group>
    </vector>
```

RECEIPT ACTIVITY FILE (in my res/layout):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
tools:context=".ReceiptActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:textColor="#fffafafa"
    android:text="OK" />

    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/ok" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/receiptBG"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@layout/receipt_background"
    android:layout_above="@id/ok">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drivingVehicle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Driving vehicle:" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which drawable exactly is causing the error? Please add a stacktrace. In general, you should use app:srcCompat instead of android:src if the source drawable is a vector.

Comment: I am using app:srcCompat now. Then I received error in gradle file about not finding VectorDrawable. Since I am using 1.5 I followed these answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693288/android-studio-1-5-1-could-not-find-property-vectordrawables  Gradle still having issues and cannot find vectordrawable. Also getting error when using app:srcCompat that "app" isn't defined even though defined xmlns:app namespace.

Comment: Thats weird. Try to put this to your activity onCreate: AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);

Comment: Also you can try to set drawable programaticaly this way: imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.drawable_image));